# Partitive X definite article

Tags: partitif

I've been struggling to understand something that must be really easy I'm failing to get it though.
What is the difference between "je veux d'argent" and "je veux de l'argent"?
Moreover, I think that in the first the "d'argent" would be "du + argent = d'argent ". 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Je veux d'argent" is ungrammatical.

"De l'" is used instead of "du" in front of words that begin with a vowel ("de l'or", "de l'iridium").

The definite article form would be "Je veux l'argent" (I want *the* money).

Comment: Merci qoba. Je le comprends maintenant !

Comment: De rien. Et en parlant de ça, on dit "je comprends", pas "je le comprends" :)

Answer (score 1):

> Je veux l'argent que tu me dois.
>
> Je veux de l'argent pour acheter une nouvelle voiture.

**=**

> I want the money you owe me.
>
> I want (some) money to buy a new car.

The partitive article (some) can be omitted in English. In French (du/de l'/des) is not omitted so.

Note also

> Je  voudrais  du  pain->J'ai besoin de pain (avoir besoin de+du/de
> la=>de).
>
> Je voudrais de l'argent->J'ai besoin d'argent (argent is a masculine
> word starting with a vowel).

Cf.

> J'ai besoin d'argent (besoin de+de la where de preposition and de la partitive article)

with

> J'ai besoin de l'argent que tu me dois.

Here (avoir besoin) de (preposition) + de la (definite article) gives de l' (du argent becomes de l'argent).

Answer (score 0):

'du' is 'de + le'. Thus, 'du + argent' is 'de + le + argent', which gives 'de l'argent'.

'd'argent' would come from 'de + argent' (e.g. 'jeu d'argent').